# Ubuntu 22.10 external monitor not working

Tags: display, monitor, external-monitor

The title says it all.

I just upgraded from Ubuntu 22.04 to 22.10, and noticed that my external monitor doesn't receive any signal anymore.

I'm connecting it with a USB-c to USB-c cable. Tried a lot of fixes I found online, none of which worked.

This is the output of `lspci -v | grep VGA -A2`:

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GA106M [GeForce RTX 3060 Mobile / Max-Q] (rev a1) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: Lenovo GA106M [GeForce RTX 3060 Mobile / Max-Q]
    Flags: fast devsel, IRQ 255, IOMMU group 9
```

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Please [edit] your question and mention what things you've tried so you can get better help.

Comment: what happens if you switch to XServer instead of wayland?

Comment: And print the output of `lspci -v | grep VGA -A2`. Add it into your question, **not** the comments

Comment: Done. As far as I can tell I'm using x11 (from the XDG_SESSION_TYPE variable)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have been having the same issue on my Lenovo Legion 5 Pro 16ITH6. The only thing that worked for me (so far) has been switching to the noveau driver and switching from switching graphics to the performance graphics card. In doing so I seem to have also lost brightness controls...

I had already tried various combinations of the kernels 5.19 and 5.15, the nvidia drivers 520 through 470, and the two graphics settings.
If you're just looking for a get-you-by solution I hope this helps, or if someone comes along with a better solution I'm eagerly awaiting it.

Edit: I tried a few more configs, I was able to get "switching" (it'll just use the iGPU) graphics to work with the noveau drivers, I had a boot with the noveau drivers with the discrete card that was super glitchy, and at one point I had the discrete graphics selected with the nvidia-470 driver.

Ensure when switching between drivers you uninstall the old one completely (and possibly reboot between installs) with:

```
sudo apt purge nvidia*
sudo apt autoremove
```

Comment: Drivers for your hardware are not ready yet. Try a distro that has more recent drivers (e.g Manjaro or Arch Linux). Otherwise @NStephenH has the correct answer.

Comment: Drivers were working fine in 22.04, though.

Comment: Hi there, thanks for the nice answer. I did manage to switch to the noveau driver, but where can I switch from the switching graphics to performance graphics card? I don't find anything online...

Comment: That is a computer specific settings, in the UEFI/BIOS config. My legion 5 shows it on the first screen, but my older laptop has it buried somewhere else in the settings.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem as you and solved it by disabling **Wayland** with:

```
sudo nano /etc/gdm3/custom.conf
```

and replace:

```
# WaylandEnable = false
```

with

```
WaylandEnable = false
```

Reboot your system and if the problem is not resolved, you can use [xrandr](https://wiki.ubuntu-it.org/Hardware/Video/Xorg/RisoluzioneSchermo) to reset the screens.

In my case, when starting the system, I have to deactivate the second screen and reactivate it immediately afterwards with:

```
sh -c "xrandr --output DisplayPort-1 --off; xrandr --output DisplayPort-1 --auto --right-of DVI-0"
```

You can find the name of the video outputs by running the [xrandr](https://wiki.ubuntu-it.org/Hardware/Video/Xorg/RisoluzioneSchermo) command in the terminal

Comment: It looks like my system now works, (with nvidia 520.56.06) and that the windowing system got set to x11 at some point (possibly an update changing it for nvidia drivers, possibly me when messing with settings)

Answer (score 0):

For me worked uninstall the driver of nvidia that came with Ubuntu 22.10 (by executing 'sudo apt purge nvidia*'), and installing the nvidia-470. Rebooted the machine, and after that the external monitor worked, but too slow - so, to fix this, I run the application 'nvidia-settings', and in one option selected the "NVIDIA (Performance Mode)" instead "NVIDIA (On Demand)".
Obs: My monitor is an Allienware AW3423DWF.

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu 22.10. For me sudo apt --reinstall install nvidia-dkms-525 made the dual monitor working again. This is with the nvidia-driver-525 and in the old x11 mode.

My problems were probably related to having secure boot enabled.

Answer (score 0):

The issue of external monitor on Ubuntu, assuming it's not a hardware problem, can be identified through the following steps:

1. Check the active graphics on your laptop in Settings -> About, then look under Graphics. If your VGA (e.g., GTX 1650) doesn't appear as active, your VGA might not be optimally utilized due to driver issues.
2. Nvidia driver issues can arise from unintentional uninstallation, conflicts (e.g., when using different CUDA versions), or secure boot problems.
3. To resolve driver issues, start by thoroughly uninstalling the existing driver using:

- sudo apt purge nvidia*
- sudo apt autoremove

4. After removing existing drivers, reinstall a compatible driver version (determining the driver version can be challenging if you don't remember the previous version), such as nvidia-driver 470, 515, or 525.
5. After driver installation, reboot. Before entering the Ubuntu OS, activate the MOK password. After entering the password, proceed to Ubuntu as usual.
6. At this point, the issue should be resolved. Verify by running nvidia-smi in the terminal. If successful, Nvidia driver information should appear, e.g., "NVIDIA-SMI 470.199.02 Driver Version: 470.199.02 CUDA Version: 11.4"

I hope these steps help you resolve the external monitor issue on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Tried everything mentioned in the suggestions but disabling secure boot solved the issue for me.
Ubuntu 22.04