# Ubuntu 23.10 display port black screen on high resolution

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, displayport

I've recently upgraded to ubuntu 23.10 on a Gigabyte G5GE Laptop.
I have 2 monitors connected, HDMI and mini-DP.
Laptop has 2 graphic cards :

```
lspci | grep VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Alder Lake-P Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 0c)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GA107M [GeForce RTX 3050 Mobile] (rev a1)
```

```
lshw -c video
  *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: GA107M [GeForce RTX 3050 Mobile]
       ...
       configuration: depth=32 driver=nvidia latency=0 mode=1920x1080 visual=truecolor xres=1920 yres=1080
  *-display
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Alder Lake-P Integrated Graphics Controller
       ...
       configuration: depth=32 driver=i915 latency=0 resolution=1920,1080
```

I was first thinking about a nvidia driver problem, and posted on nvidia forum but it looks like it's more a i915 problem : https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/ubuntu-23-10-display-port-not-working-on-ga107m-rtx-3050-mobile/271143

If i switch to a lower resolution on the DP (1280x720) the screen works, but not in native 1920x1080. Everything was working file with Ubuntu 23.04.

xrandr working :

```
xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 5120 x 1385, maximum 16384 x 16384
eDP-1 connected primary 1920x1080+3200+305 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 194mm
   1920x1080    144.17*+ 144.17  
   1680x1050    144.17  
   ...
HDMI-1 connected 1920x1080+1280+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 527mm x 296mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+  74.97    50.00    59.94  
   1680x1050     59.88  
   ...
DP-1 connected 1280x720+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 527mm x 296mm
   1920x1080     60.00 +  74.97    50.00    59.94  
   1680x1050     59.95  
   ...
HDMI-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

Xrandr when the second external monitor is on 1920 (black) :

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 4920 x 1920, maximum 16384 x 16384
eDP-1 connected primary 1920x1080+3000+305 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 194mm
   1920x1080    144.17*+ 144.17  
   1680x1050    144.17  
   ...
HDMI-1 connected 1920x1080+1080+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 527mm x 296mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+  74.97    50.00    59.94  
   1680x1050     59.88  
   ...
DP-1 connected 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 527mm x 296mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+  74.97    50.00    59.94  
   1680x1050     59.95  
   ...
HDMI-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

nvidia driver is the one recommanded by ubuntu-drivers :

```
nvidia-driver-545 - third-party non-free recommended
```

I've tried to disable Wayland without results :
[Ubuntu 22.10 external monitor not working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1436706/ubuntu-22-10-external-monitor-not-working)

I'm not really sure what is wrong here, if it's a driver problem or not, if it's due to nvidia or intel graphic card... i'm a bit lost and don't know what i can try.

Thanks a lot for your read and your help ;)

Comment: I solved the problem by buying a mini-DP to HDMI cable, i can't explain why but this way the monitor is working great.
That does not sounds logical for me, as the output is still in DP, supposing the problem is more on the monitor, but it was working on the previous ubuntu version, so... i'll let this question opened for now if somebody else is experiencing it.